# XText and JVMTypes

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I'm trying to get a really simple example going with the latest version of xtext (2.12). Per the documentation: https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/305_xbase.html#xbase-language-ref-introduction

My .xtext file looks like this:

```
grammar org.mylang.MyLang with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes" as jvmTypes

generate evidently "http://www.mylang.org/MyLang"

DataType:
  'datatype' name=ID 
  'mapped-to' javaType=[jvmTypes::JvmType|QualifiedName];

QualifiedName: ID ('.' ID)* ;
```

However, after I generate the artifacts and fire up the eclipse editor, although syntax highlighting works, I get an error any time I try to reference a JVM type. For example:

```
datatype xxxx mapped-to java.util.Date
```

I get an error line under `java.util.Date`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xtype` instead of `with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals`. Also observe the changes in generated infrastructure in `src-gen` folder.

Comment: It works! But why? And how? It seems like bringing in xType added a lot of things to the  namespace (e.g., QualifiedName is IN xType). Is there a way to do this without importing all these things?

Comment: Also, where can I see precisely what xType is defining?

Comment: you can have a look at the generated bindings in the AbstractXXXModules  with xtype and copy and paste them to your runtime/ui module without xtype

Comment: @jsinglet, you can open the declaration of `Xtype` grammar with F3 at `with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xtype`. Some predefined language constructs might be useful for you, e.g. `JvmTypeReference`.

Comment: @jsinglet, inspect `DefaultCommonTypesRuntimeModule` and `DefaultCommonTypesUiModule` to learn about the infrastructure of languages based on `Xtype`.